# Google Adsense ads not displaying - CSS issue?

Tags: css, adsense

For some reason, the ads do not always display in IE and Firefox but ALWAYS displays in Chrome when I use my laptop.

When I change to desktop, it randomly displays ads on all browsers ... Coverage is about 60%... I think there is an issue with my CSS but I can't figure it out.

Here is the site: http://www.cardiologia.xyz/

Comment: I am not able to see adds on chrome either. adds working right now? are you sure?

Comment: I can see when I use my laptop.... 100% .... However, when I use my desktop it's 50/50 .... did you use laptop or desktop?

Comment: I have both and checked on both but still cant see the adds, will you pls take a screenshot on both the screens and share